# Modifying scope variables in an event in a directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a jQuery event on an element in a directive’s link function.  I want to modify a scope variable in that event callback.  It’d not working- the template that renders that variable never updates:

```
joyableApp.directive('foobar', [function() {
  var FoobarLink = function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.foo = 'bar';
    element.click(function(){
      console.log("clicked!");
      scope.foo = 'clicked_result';
    });
  };
  return {
    template: '<div>foo = {{foo}}</div>',
    scope: {},
    link: FoobarLink
  }
}]);
```

In this example, I’m trying to update `scope.foo` when the directive element is clicked.  However, when I run this and click the element, the template is not updated from `bar` to `clicked_result`.  I suspect I’m missing something fundamental about how `link` and `scope` work here.

Some unrelated backstory, just in case it helps: I’m trying to create a directive that would go on an `<input>` field.  When you focus on this input field, it’ll display a popup tooltip.  So the interface to use the directive would look like `<input input-tooltip content=‘some tooltip content here’>`.  However, to do that, I need the directive to listen on the root element for `focus` events.  The only way I can find to do that is to use a jQuery event on the element passed in to the link function.  However, in the callback for the focus event on that event, I can’t seem to successfully modify scope variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.foo` will not be refreshed until Angular runs into [digest loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop), which is the so called `dirty check`. In directive, you need to manually trigger a digest loop youself, like below

```
scope.$apply(function () {
  scope.foo = 'clicked_result';
});
```

But you might run into `Error: $digest already in progress`, so you'd better use `evalAsync` or `applyAsync` to trigger a safe digest cycle,like

```
scope.$evalAsync(function () {
  scope.foo = 'clicked_result';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap the DOM manipulation in a $timeout.

```
  element.click(function(){
    console.log("clicked!");
    $timeout(function () {
      scope.foo = 'clicked_result';
    },0);

  });
```

The $timeout will cause a safe digest cycle to begin.
Don't forget to inject $timeout:

```
joyableApp.directive('foobar', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
  element.click(function(){
    console.log("clicked!");
    scope.$apply(function () {
      scope.foo = 'clicked_result';
    });

  });
```

Using $apply is appropriate here and doesn't require injection of $timeout.  In my experience, $timeout is useful only in situations where you modify the DOM in the link function and need to wait for angular to compile the added elements.

Comment: The danger in using apply is you can't verify angular is not in a digest cycle when using it, unless you use $$phase, which is not supposed to be used as it's a 'private' property. Mishko has offered the $timeout as the best-practice way of doing a safe apply.

Comment: There is no "danger" in this case, and the best practice is in fact to use $apply.  Angular itself uses $apply for all but 2 of the 16 ng-{{event}} directives, and use evalAsync in those two cases primarily to address browser differences.  Mishko's advice applies primarily to situations where you're not sure whether you are in a digest cycle or not, which almost invariably means you've already fallen victim to an anti-pattern.  The only times I've found $timeout truly necessary were when trying to wrap jQuery plugins into directives (an anti pattern in an of itself).